# Не работает map в react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

Делаю запрос к апи, полученный массив с данными кладется в стэйт. Дальше я пытаюсь в return пройтись по этому массиву map'ом - выдается ошибка map is not a function. Что я делаю не так?

Array.isArray(topFilms) - true, это точно массив.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import { FilmPreviewCard } from "components/FilmPreviewCard";


const kinopoiskAPI_URL = "https://kinopoiskapiunofficial.tech";
const APItopFilms = "/api/v2.2/films/top?type=TOP_100_POPULAR_FILMS&page=1";

export function TopFilmsPage() {
    const [topFilms, setTopFilms] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getTopFilms() {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get(kinopoiskAPI_URL + APItopFilms, {
                    headers: {
                        'example': 'example',
                    }
                });
                setTopFilms(topFilms.push(response.data.films));
                console.log(Array.isArray(topFilms));
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }

        getTopFilms();
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            {topFilms.map((film, idx) => <FilmPreviewCard
                key={idx}
                id={film.filmId}
                title={film.nameRu}
                img={film.posterUrlPreview} />)}
        </div>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо `setTopFilms(topFilms.push(response.data.films))` нужно `setTopFilms(response.data.films)`.

А `Array.isArray(topFilms)` выдает `true` потому что `setState` работает асинхронно и сразу после вызова `setTopFilms` в переменной `topFilms` еще остается предыдущее значение (пустой массив).

Comment: Спасибо, сработало.

Comment: Наверное, асинхронно)

Comment: @ДенисСтепанов Спасибо, исправил